# How do I keep the DIV from jumping onMouseOver?

Tags: jquery, onmouseover, slidedown, slideup, onmouseout

The goal of this little snippet is to (by default) show image data then remove it via "slideDown" onMouseOver. It works mostly, however when the info is displayed if you hover over the text, the div jumps up and down crazy-like. Any help to remedy this is appreciated!

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/voudini/SggsV/

Answer (score 4):

Try using `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`

Try this

```
$('.hoverbox')
    .mouseenter(function(){
        $(".hoverinfo", this).stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
    })
    .mouseleave(function(e){

        $(".hoverinfo", this).stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SggsV/3/)

Check its documentation

[Mouse Enter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and
[Mouse Leave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the
>   mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

Comment: Welcome..Glad to see it helps u..pls accept the answer if it helps